# Рекурсивно обойти JSON с помощью circe-optics

Tags: scala

Допустим есть `JSON` со сложной структурой:

```
{
  "a":"aa",
  "b":"bb",
  "c":[
    "aaa",
    "bbb"
  ],
  "d":{
    "e":"ee",
    "f":"ff"
  }
}
```

И я хочу перевести в верхний регистр все строки. В доке нашел только такое:

```
root.each.string.modify(_.toUpperCase)
```

Ожидаемо апперкейсятся только рутовые поля.

Можно ли как-то рекурсивно обойти всю джсонку и применить мою функцию? 
Структура `json` заранее не известна.

Вот пример на [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/m3BX15v3TaKK5y3mNQNILw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так

```scala
lazy val f: Json => Json =
  root.string.modify(_.toUpperCase) compose root.each.json.modify(f(_))
```

Только имейте в ввиду, что при глубокой вложенности вполне может произойти переполнение стека.

Comment: Спасибо! Глубокой не будет.